# Windows batch: Sequence Number Generator to CSV file

Tags: batch-file, csv, cmd

I am trying to write a batch script which does the following actions:

1. Read arguments inserted into the 'startCounter' & 'endCounter' variable
2. Having a step value of 1
3. Write to concurrent CSV files to multiple directories. All CSV file contains the same data, only writing to different directories.

I have tested the following code successfully. For some reasons when I change value '1006000' to some other values like '00000001' and etc, the script does not work.

```
@ECHO OFF

for /l %%x in (1006000,1,1007000) do (
    echo %%x
    echo %%x>>C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\script\testdata1\ORDER_ID5.csv
    echo %%x>>C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\script\ASAP\testdata2\ORDER_ID5.csv
    echo %%x>>C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\script\ASAP\testdata3\ORDER_ID5.csv
    echo %%x>>C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\script\ASAP\testdata4\ORDER_ID5.csv
    echo %%x>>C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\script\ASAP\testdata5\ORDER_ID5.csv
    echo %%x>>C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\script\ASAP\testdata6\ORDER_ID5.csv
    echo %%x>>C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\script\ASAP\testdata7\ORDER_ID5.csv
    echo %%x>>C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\script\ASAP\testdata8\ORDER_ID5.csv

)
```

Hence, I am trying to make a more flexible script which generates CSV file, and the CSV filename displays total records generated by the batch script.

```
@ECHO OFF

set startCounter = 1000000
set endCounter = 1050000

set totalRecords = %endCounter%-%startCounter%
set name = NewDataGen_%startCounter%_to_%endCounter%_%totalRecords%.csv


for /l %%x in (%startCounter%,1,%endCounter%) do (
   echo %%x
   echo %%x>>%name%
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What sort of abomination is this?  Certainly not bash!  It looks like...Windows stuff, but you say bash several times.

Comment: Sorry, it's Batch scripting in Windows.

Comment: Then why on earth does the code say `#!/bin/bash` at the top?

Comment: Sorry, corrected the script already but still unable to generate any output. Could you kindly assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are simple to solve and consistent in nature.

```
set startCounter = 1000000
set endCounter = 1050000
```

as examples.

The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures that any trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned to `var`.

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

**But** the `set/a` syntax acts less particularly **and MUST** be used for calculations. It **only** works for integer values.

```
set startCounter=1000000
```

will work happily, **if** there are no trailing spaces on the line

```
set /a startCounter=1000000
```

will work happily, regardless of trailing spaces

```
set /a startCounter = 1000000
```

will also work happily, regardless of trailing spaces

```
set /a totalRecords = %endCounter%-%startCounter%
set /a totalRecords=%endCounter%-%startCounter%
set /a totalRecords = endCounter-startCounter
set /a totalRecords=endCounter-startCounter
```

(and other constructs) Will all calculate `totalrecords` (case is largely irrelevant in batch.) The `/a` means 'process in arithmetic mode'.

(Personal preference for the second format. YMMV)

Comment: Very important observation: a batch variable is **always** a string. It cam operate as an integer **if** it contains an integer-string. Leading zeroes complicate matters. A leading zero interprets the value as **Octal** so `0123` and `123` are different values. To obtain leading zeroes, add 1000000000 to the value and then access `%var:~-n%` which means "the last n characters of the variable `var`" That's not the whole story, of course..lots more fun to be had with batch!

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it already. The script is as below. Thanks a lot Magoo!

```
@ECHO OFF

set /a startCounter=1000000
set /a endCounter=1000100

set /a totalRecords=%endCounter%-%startCounter%
set name=NewDataGen_%startCounter%_%endCounter%_%totalRecords%.csv

for /l %%x in (%startCounter%,1,%endCounter%) do (
   echo %%x
   echo %%x>>%name%
)
```